# p5.js 'width' variable not working?

Tags: javascript, width, p5.js

**Hi!** I was making a replica of 10 PRINT *http://10print.org* following Dan Shiffman's *(a.k.a. The Coding Train on YT)* tutorial for Processing. I was taking the same approach, but when using the `width` variable in the `if` statement: `if (width < posX) {posY = posY + 20;}`, the posY value was not changed.

**Here is My Code:**

```js
var posX, posY;

function setup() {
 createCanvas(640, 360);
 background(0);
 posX = 0;
 posY = 0;
}

function draw() {
 strokeWeight(2);
 stroke(255);
 if(random(0, 1) > 0.5) {
  line(posX, posY, posX+20, posY+20);
 } else {
  line(posX, posY+20, posX+20, posY);
 }
 posX = posX + 20;
 if (width < posX) {
  posY = posY + 20;
 };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>10 PRINT</title>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.0/p5.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well have you added `console.log("width is " + width + " posX is " + posX)` before the `if` statement?

Comment: width returned 640 and posX returned 0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100 as both should have...

Comment: Well is 640 less than any of those `posX` values? The `<` operator returns true when the value on the left is strictly less than the value on the right.

Comment: no i mean it kept counting by 20 forever...

Comment: Did the value ever get greater than 640? (Well nothing stops it, so it should eventually.) When it's greater than or equal to 640, then `posY` will be incremented.

Comment: yes currently at 45600

Comment: Maybe also write the value of `posY` to the console. That code will work as written; it's not like JavaScript is broken.

Comment: Thanks for some reason I found a soulution

Answer (score 0):

When you go down to the next line (by increasing `posY`), you probably want to go back to the left of the screen, by resetting `posX`. Something like this:

```
if (width < posX) {
    posY = posY + 20;
    posX = 0;
};
```

If you don't do this, then `posY` will just keep increasing by `20` every frame.